# How can you maintain breathable air in a sealed location long term?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, breathing

Wizard Bob has created himself a mighty tower, but being a reclusive, paranoid crazy sort of Wizard he'd like to create it entirely sealed to stop anything getting in that he doesn't want inside.

The problem is that he'll rapidly run out of breathable air inside that tower and that's a problem as Bob likes to be able to breathe.

The [air bubble](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/air-bubble) spell creates a short term (1 min/lvl) pocket of air for breathing air, but that's no good for Bob's familiar or any creatures he summons and wants to chat with.

How can Bob ensure there is a fresh supply of air in his tower fortress without adding any holes in the wall?

Items are sub-par unless they affect an area rather than a single person.
Spells are only OK if they will still be working when Bob has been away for a month or three.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

He could use a planar gate to the plane of air to get air into his tower - that might be a security breach though.

He might however just do a trick used in Sci Fi: have an air refreshing system in the shape of a garden. This does need the wizard Bob to make some sort of indoor sun (a keystone with a permanent or semi permanent [light spell](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/light.html)? Possibly [daylight](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/daylight.html#daylight)? Or rather a pulsed [sunburst](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/sunburst.html#sunburst) to kill off the mold and funghi?) To sustain a human, the garden would need to produce about 550 liters of oxygen per day, while a typical potted plant makes something like 5ml oxygen per hour. But a mature tree could (depending on sources) provide enough oxygen to sustain an adult and a child 24/7 with a day/night cycle. If he wants some overhead: plant some trees in the cellar and provide them with enough light.

Comment: Nice idea! A bit more digging underground to do to fit those trees in then!

Comment: Another, possibly more manageable, oxygen source might be some sort of algae.  Since this is a wizard's tower in a fantasy setting, of course it wouldn't be unexpected for the algae to be mobile and/or carnivorous, as Jaejatae notes in his answer.

Comment: This seems like the most workable and realistic solution, with some magical water and light generation BoB can have a magical underground garden for growing herbs and plants and not suffocate as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Some alchemical device could be able to continuously make new fresh air : after all it's just basic chemistry. Eventually it could need an alchemist minion to repair it once a while.

Keep in mind that the fact an object is not in the books doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Planting a bunch of trees and keeping the sun shining through the windows would easily do the job, he can procede to seal the tower once the trees are already at a certain age and able to sustain the environment.

Or he could bring already grown trees in.

Make them carnivores to add security, if you like.

Comment: Trees don't work that way. The sunlight is not just to make them grow, but is also what they use to make their breathing work and “sustain the environment” as a side effect of breathing. Sealing up the trees without sunlight after they've grown would just give you dead trees.

Answer (score -1):

Everyone so far were looking for a way to give Bob some air, but what about removing the need to breathe air. I assume that being a reclusive Wizard, Bob would not invite guest in his tower

- You could turn Bob into a undead
- Equip him with a Necklace of Adaptation (9000 gp)
- Or an Iridescent Ioun stone (18,000 gp/No slot taken)

Comment: There is an explicit need for familiars and "creatures he summons" to be able to breath. However, welcome to rpg.se !

Comment: also, the question was: "How to ensure air supply without any holes in the wall?" and there was a request for Items to be of area effect  (inclusive)  or more than 1 person.

Answer (score -1):

I might coat the ceilings with a moss or algae that not only produces oxygen but also glows (and possibly watches for anything Bob doesn't want happening in his tower).

But of course that introduces another problem: how do you provide whatever the algae lives on?